# Characteristic function of an asymmetric Laplace distributed random variable

Tags: integration, random-variables, exponential-function, characteristic-functions

What is the characteristic function of a random variable with density

$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2} [ 1_{x>0} \, a e^{-a x} + 1_{x<0} \, b e^{b x} ], \; \; \; \quad a,b > 0 \quad \quad  ? $$

My hopefully still shortenable result is so far
$$\phi_X(t) = E[e^{itX}] = \frac{b}{2} \int_{-\infty}^0  e^{itx} e^{bx} dx + \frac{a}{2} \int_0^{\infty}  e^{itx} e^{-ax} dx$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} (a e^{itx} e^{-ax} + b e^{-itx} e^{-bx}) dx $$
There is some analogy to the fact that a r.v. with above density and $a=b$, i.e. a Laplace distributed r.v., is distributed as the difference of two exponential $(a)$-distributed r.v.'s, which can be proved via the characteristic functions (see eg. [c.f. of exp. dist.](http://www.statlect.com/ucdexp1.htm) or on this forum).

It is therefore worth a try to suppose that a r.v. with the above density with $a \neq b$ is distributed as the difference $Z$ of an exponential $(a)$-distributed r.v. and an exponential $(b)$-distributed r.v.. Is it correct $Z$ has characteristic function
$$\phi_Z(t) = \frac{a \,b}{ab + it(a-b) + t^2 } \quad \quad ?$$

(Remark. A r.v. distributed with the density $f_X$ is sometimes called asymmetric Laplace density, although this terminus was used mainly for a different formulation, see eg. [Kozubowski & Podgorski (2000)](http://scholar.google.de/scholar_url?url=http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0895717701001145&hl=de&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm03oeZFKE0yubtk9aeYeC8wCZbHrA&nossl=1&oi=scholarr&ei=ucg0VfOTCcT0Op2OgcgC&ved=0CB8QgAMoADAA).)